# How to retrieve data with relation (Backendless)

Tags: ios, database, swift, backendless

I am using backendless to save users objects in a database. 
I have a relation from my users table to a address table with two columns called "city" and "country". How can I retrieve this objects?

Comment: Hi. Have you looked at documentation - https://backendless.com/documentation/data/ios/data_relations_retrieve.htm?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the relation retrieval API: https://backendless.com/documentation/data/rest/data_relations_retrieve.htm

There are examples available here:

https://backendless.com/feature-21-loading-related-data-objects-the-auto-load-approach/
https://backendless.com/feature-22-loading-related-data-objects-the-one-stepdynamic-approach/
https://backendless.com/feature-28-loading-related-data-objects-the-semi-lazy-approach/